# Why are there several modules in Perl with the same name but different file size?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am trying to install [GeneMark-ES](http://topaz.gatech.edu/GeneMark/) but when trying to run as specified in the documentation several PERL modules are missing. I have tried to point to all the necessary files by defining PERL5LIB variable.

However, I have come across several files which are installed but there is more than one file in various directories. Not only that, each file has different file sizes.

Why is that happening? What file should I use?

Here is a GUI search for files named `Simple.pm`

[image: GUI search]

Comment: When you try to run GeneMark-ES, what happens, including the _exact text_ of any error messages you receive? How does this differ from what you expect to happen? What makes you think that `Simple.pm` might be in any way related to the problem?

Comment: The error output is: `Can't locate simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: "Directories in this variable") BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./gmes_petap.pl line 82.`

I have gone past it by copying one by one every file in the screenshot into the expected path. Eventually, I stopped receiving errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read [***Perl Modules***](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) from the documentation to understand how Perl uses module names

After absorbing that, you will see that there are in reality only three different library locations which together contain ten module files that end with `Simple.pm`

- `/home/pollo/perl5/lib/perl5`
- `/usr/share/perl5/core_perl`
- `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl`

Nowhere is there anything that looks like `GeneMark-ES`, but it seems unlikely that it would end with `::Simple` if it were even there

Please open a ***new question*** and describe your experience trying to install the module that you require instead of offering misleading and irrelevant facts

Answer (score 4):

Those `Simple.pm` files are module files, and each one is for a different "distribution".

For example, the one highlighted in the image is for [Locale::Maketext::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::Maketext::Simple). `Simple.pm` is the actual module file itself. The first one in the image is for [Bio::Location::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Location::Simple) etc. The `Bio/Location` part of the path signifies the actual name of the distribution as you can see.

The installation instructions should outline exactly which distributions it requires. You don't just use the `Simple.pm` file directly.

Comment: How do I choose the right distribution for the program I am trying to run?

Comment: The program should have documentation regarding which distributions to use.

Comment: @minombreespollo: Pretty much any version of the modules should at least compile. **stevieb** hasn't explained this very well, but you should start by removing `PERL5LIB` altogether. If you will copy and paste that text into your question instead of posting images then we can progress from there. Please also show the result of `perl -E 'say for @INC'`

Comment: @minombreespollo: You shouldn't mark a question as being accepted until all of the issues in your question have been fulfilled. Most people won't look at questions with an accepted answer.

Comment: @minombreespollo: Please also add the output of `which -a perl` *in texr format*.

Comment: *"Those `Simple.pm` files are module files, and each one is for a different "distribution""* While this has been exacerbated by the OP latching on to the first "answer" that appeared, what you write is highly misleading if not downright wrong. The OP's list shows *ten distinct modules*, and while different modules will of course have different "distributions", it's far from being useful to explain things that way. Please don't post solutions unless you are pretty much certain of what you are saying.